# Saída de caracteres acentuados mal formatados em C no Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, acentuação

Apesar de estar importando a biblioteca referente à acentuação, as saídas dos caracteres acentuados saem totalmente desconfigurados do normal.

Esse problema só acontece no Visual Studio Code, o mesmo código no Dev C funciona normal.

Abaixo o código:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdbool.h> 
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <locale.h>

    bool E_Primo(int Numero){
        for (int i = 2; i < Numero; i++)
            if (Numero % i == 0)
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    int main(){
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
        int Numero;
        printf("Digite um número para verificar se ele é primo ou não: ");
        scanf("%d", &Numero);
        
        while (Numero <= 0){
            printf("Número invalido para saber se é primo ou nao\nDigite uma número maior que 0");
            scanf("%d", &Numero);
        }  
        
        if (E_Primo(Numero))
             printf("Seu número %d é primo ", Numero);
        else
             printf("Seu número %d não é primo ", Numero);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Dependendo do terminal que está configurado no VS Code isso está dentro do esperado. Não é todo terminal que dá suporte a caracteres além da tabela ASCII.

Comment: Na minha experiência pessoal, não se deve utilizar outro idioma ao não ser o inglês em um código fonte, pois isso sempre foi e será um problema, já que existem dezenas de tabelas e formas de codificação de caracteres acentuados. O VSCode pode estar usando UTF-8. Esse pode funcionar bem em um Linux mas vai ser um desastre em um terminal Windows. O correto, embora não seja trivial para um pequeno programa, é utilizar uma biblioteca que usará uma tabela para "traduzir" para outro idioma. Isso é um outro problema, claro.